# Can I get a more portable receiver for my Logitech wireless mouse?

Tags: logitech-mouse

I have a [Logitech Trackman mouse](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Logitech-Wireless-TrackMan-Wheel-Mouse/dp/B000092QUR), which I love and would like to take with me on my travels.

However, the receiver for this thing is highly unportable (for use on a train, for example):

[image]

I know you can get tiny wireless receivers like on this mouse:

[image]

Is there any way to use a smaller third party receiver with my Logitech mouse, or does anyone know of a Logitech accessory or something like that which I could use?

Answer (score 0):

From the Amazon link you posted, the new version uses a smaller receiver... although from other internet posts asking for the same thing it is a different trackball layout.

Your other option would be to disassemble the existing receiver and keep only the parts required and build a new case out of something RF-transparent.

Comment: Note: a different receiver for the 'same' product is not necessarily compatible. The MX Revolution mouse for example has two editions, with different receivers, and they're not cross-compatible.